# Uploading to SharepointOnline subfolder using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

it seems like I can upload a file to SPO's Site Collection URL but not the subfolder. For example, I can upload to "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/Reporting", but not "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/Reporting/Sales". Here's the working code's relevant bit:

```
$Username = "me@domain.com"
$Password = "Password"
$SiteCollectionUrl = "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/Reporting"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$DocLibName = "Sales"

$Folder="C:\MySalesFolder"

    Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
    {
       $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
       return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    }
     $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteCollectionUrl)
     $Context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

    #Retrieve list
    $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
    $Context.Load($List)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #Upload file
    Foreach ($File in (dir $Folder -File))
    {
    $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
    $FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
    $Upload = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
    $Context.Load($Upload)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

I tried to hardcode "/Sales" subfolder but no luck. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Trying to upload files to subfolder in Sharepoint Online via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397084/trying-to-upload-files-to-subfolder-in-sharepoint-online-via-powershell) You will need to amend the FileCreationURL:

```
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $List.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $FolderName + "/" + $File.Name
```

I believe you just need to prepend $File.Name with the Folder path to your root directory.

**Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl Method:**

Alternatively to attempting to Upload via List.RootFolder..., you can use the "GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl" method to get your Target Folder

```
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
$Context.Load($List.RootFolder) 
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$FolderName = "Sales"

$TargetFolder = $Context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($List.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $FolderName);
```

Then for upload you would use

```
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $File.Name
$UploadFile = $TargetFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Context.Load($UploadFile)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: I tried to set $FolderName ="Sales", but its throwing an error Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Comment: What output do you get from $FileCreationInfo.URL after setting it like that above?

Comment: URL: "/Reporting/Sales/Foo.txt". I guess it's missing the sharepoint.com preceding URL? Foo.txt is my test file

Comment: It seems like it's missing the Base URL Path, but I'm unsure if that's an issue or not as the Context should contain that information anyway. I've added another method for retrieving the target folder. From there you should get some feedback from the $TargetFolder object as to whether it's able to resolve the Target folder successfully or not.

Comment: Sorry, meant "/Sales/Foo.txt". I had Reporting in there for testing.

Comment: $TargetFolder is missing the base URL path as well. So I'm thinking that is probably not the issue as you said. Also, I was successful in uploading to the base URL itself, and when I checked the $FileCreationInfo.URL during debug it was showing blank too.

Comment: Do you get anything from the output of $List.RootFolder.Folders?

Comment: Update: I was able to send the file to Sales folder! But I cheated. I hardcoded the URL: $FileCreationInfo.URL = "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/Reporting/Sales" + $File.Name. But this is unwieldy and I'm not sure why the variable isn't working as described in your code snippet? I have lot of folders and this will help me resolve the problem more efficiently

Comment: While I'm not sure why it's not returning the relative path correctly. However, enumerating folders and uploading per folder shouldn't be too difficult, I'll adjust the answer to reflect similar.

Comment: One Question first, the DocLibName should be the root name of the store? Shouldn't it be "Reporting". Perhaps it's returning a blank object for that List, hence the lack of results.